# How to resolve the Error "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Actually I'm making a java application in Netbeans its working fine for a while when i add one more component in this application, I get the error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class demo
Java Result: 1
```

when i delete this component then again its working fine.I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: Provide you code

Comment: Also, please provide the complete stacktrace.  Alternatively, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18093929/139985

Comment: code is too long

Comment: i have red all answer but i am not getting solution

Comment: How do you expect us to help you then? Do you have a class named `demo`? Does it have a `public static void main(String[])` method?

Comment: Is your class under the right package??

Comment: yes class under in right package

Comment: Right click the project node, select "Properties", from the "Categories" section, select "Run", make sure that the `demo` class (or the actual `main` class) is selected, if need be, click `Browse` and select it from one of the available classes listed

Comment: i have done this and code in working fine for a while but when i add  one more component of swing then error occure

Comment: can be it size problem?